# postgres only using sorted index for querying 5m records table

Tags: postgresql

I'm having some issues with a 5M record table.
it has a few indexes.

this is the one being used:

```
CREATE INDEX emails_ordered_created_and_keys
ON vsko_mailer_api_prod.emails USING btree
("$$meta.created" ASC NULLS LAST, key ASC NULLS LAST)
TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

I'm doing a query like this:

```
SELECT
    "key",
    "job",
    "sentDate",
    "scheduledDate",
    "status",
    "recipient",
    "opens",
    "clicks",
    "smtpEvents",
    "$$meta.deleted",
    "$$meta.created",
    "$$meta.modified",
    "$$meta.version",
    "$$meta.deleted",
    "$$meta.created",
    "$$meta.modified"
FROM
    "emails"
WHERE
    "emails"."$$meta.deleted" = FALSE
    AND ("emails"."$$meta.created" > '2018-02-13T14:30:35.679075Z'
        OR ("emails"."$$meta.created" = '2018-02-13T14:30:35.679075Z'
            AND "emails"."key" > '8c0a3151-bf17-490f-8124-d93f7482624f'))
ORDER BY
    "$$meta.created" ASC,
    "key" ASC
LIMIT '500'
```

The problem is that it is only using the emails_ordered_created_and_keys index.

```
"Limit  (cost=0.11..192.72 rows=500 width=764) (actual time=1.122..1.701 rows=500 loops=1)"
"  ->  Index Scan using emails_ordered_created_and_keys on emails  (cost=0.11..1966725.65 rows=5105459 width=764) (actual time=1.120..1.664 rows=500 loops=1)"
"        Filter: ((NOT ""$$meta.deleted"") AND ((""$$meta.created"" > '2018-02-13 14:30:35.679075+00'::timestamp with time zone) OR ((""$$meta.created"" = '2018-02-13 14:30:35.679075+00'::timestamp with time zone) AND (key > '8c0a3151-bf17-490f-8124-d93f7482624f'::uuid))))"
"        Rows Removed by Filter: 1000"
"Planning Time: 0.297 ms"
"Execution Time: 1.749 ms"
```

readable version here: https://explain.depesz.com/s/ajW2

as I'm going down the table, by the time I'm at 2019, it has to filter out so many rows that the query takes ages.

I'm not sure what index i would need for this case. I have an index on `$$meta.created` as well. (example: https://explain.depesz.com/s/Ju9O)

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: you should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble than they are worth it. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name i wish i could!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the query to

```
WHERE NOT emails."$$meta.deleted" = FALSE
  AND (emails."$$meta.created", emails.key) >
      ('2018-02-13T14:30:35.679075Z', '8c0a3151-bf17-490f-8124-d93f7482624f')
```

and use this index:

```
CREATE INDEX ON emails ("$$meta.created", key)
   WHERE NOT emails."$$meta.deleted";
```

Explanation: [`OR` is a performance problem](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/avoid-or-for-better-performance/). By rewriting it as a lexicographical comparison of pairs, you get rid of the `OR`, and a simple index scan finds the rows efficiently. PostgreSQL is no longer tempted to use the index that supports the `ORDER BY`.

Comment: i'm going to assume the  = FALSE should be omitted :)

Comment: 0.7ms. this is amazing. can you explain why this makes such a big difference?

Comment: The `= FALSE` is not wrong, just inelegant. I have added an explanation.