# Postgres selecting bad execution plan. vaccuum analyze doesn't seem to change its mind

Tags: postgresql

This query

```
select "key","job","sentDate","scheduledDate","status","recipient","mergeVariables","opens","clicks","smtpEvents", "$$meta.deleted", "$$meta.created", "$$meta.modified", "$$meta.version", "$$meta.deleted", "$$meta.created", "$$meta.modified" from "emails" 
where "emails"."$$meta.deleted" = false 
and "job" in ('6f0b0288-6edd-408f-a0a9-8406fcf4bd88','a36c901c-b2df-427f-8a83-8e7072c1ad55','87127ee7-b13f-4a60-b981-65ea91988bcd','76a3eef0-32b3-4cd2-b6df-2e3360ec484a','893fd688-e789-49b8-9f95-cbaf84520852','3dc85b85-2de4-4e71-b9e0-26dbb122acfd','ae0615b1-2520-45d0-9159-b7794e535bc5','39562342-afa3-4054-82c6-cda103b205d7','6995b876-1781-4e84-b6cb-437ccb45fd4c','adfd15ce-e68a-405c-a18c-fa01daa711ea','901a9e3a-2c0d-476d-97b3-c64b954f0ecc','e6dec9f0-f670-4187-b0a4-fb8a676f0016','a373c541-32c8-4070-8ac0-209683257fe5','5ff6cec9-794f-49f1-9043-cc9120c3b1d4','3d2226c2-7559-41c7-b1e5-688830693ca2','b08bcf0b-fde2-4079-bfc4-aeff9bac48a7','e82eae7f-4e41-410d-9eb9-4b49d7ccde11','d0ae300f-5f8a-4851-9c56-3d87dad3ce2e','fc3c11df-7cd6-4819-888f-8abd2e32367b','0a27151a-3f33-488c-a3e6-4ffcfe9f7020','9b89d3f2-4484-4109-aaeb-382ef480b0e1','9ef54c01-2fe2-4ed9-8d34-6f3fa8108040','21a63e3a-bbdc-43e3-9c73-73c94e8a3ac3','f90ac6c0-d422-4e8c-9dcc-64a8a38f15e4','39d2c420-fbb1-4883-a184-9670c3b5ecb6','63681ea2-e567-4f6f-9b64-32c63d7d7f67','38d7e27b-86ce-4e05-a2eb-a50925e8afab','96dd4ec2-f2d6-44b4-bb0c-97025f6af7e5','4a9cb1ab-6a3e-47d5-9348-51efd918883f','cdd6b061-3a05-47cf-bba3-067ce03d81e7','ef9b60da-b26e-4f60-805a-5b1778a08288','0dcb9ea7-fa78-4c64-bf4b-4d62eb27be8e','104f4306-042c-4df9-bbf2-7c6d7ec5999d','340e95e3-0ff1-435b-babb-029533cd67ff','f5e8c4a1-a0ec-44b7-a84c-4e2bea03dab6','3acb7147-1fc9-4911-93b1-28b0b3316027','7874342e-b3d2-48e1-9ab8-bf3896ff5d69','3c1083e9-9b62-4ae4-9969-55e5813cb566','77afa7ae-436c-4d81-8917-a7bd787447ca','6615613e-5e22-48ce-bca6-1098c086d194','e2e28dab-9e68-41ca-8f98-a95e5c711d7d','ac1140cb-b3f0-4d4c-9236-8242851a4594','53254e80-eaee-4609-b141-b5f3eb50b33d','565fc864-5088-47f4-a5d3-4d1ea2b74e4b','fa4c7805-7208-4a17-9fcb-bfb4cdbbb6b8','7b5a0507-b59c-4de5-b738-7095c561fdd7','4727cc2b-7cb2-4009-bcd5-d20b22390b7d','7ed66544-7d5a-4eda-9cbf-f2a9ab2e8714','327989bd-83d7-4950-81a3-d9569f4b9bd8','aa4ae2b3-b3b0-41ef-8e7b-894fa85c9c70','3fe328f5-5ee6-46bb-8448-dd7e306400fb','29b2c9e0-8302-44bd-939d-3d8a5e242902','7303852d-6b5f-4210-a2df-b755dcc81417','6cb6d3ca-9ba5-4c2d-8cf3-08168cd14933','12fd7ace-5755-4b71-ac9f-cd0fb529873e','dd3a2020-3378-4603-8d70-60047e8189cc','cc9240c4-9d28-4d82-825d-bb88be3ec640','bbf5f70d-d828-44e1-867e-ff29c8945c1b','a11f458e-3176-4ffd-aaf4-71c6aca70a53','24d574d0-57de-41b3-9380-8968c0ab02f5','57de56d7-cdc2-4004-9853-65df9c3e0871','cef46cd7-bac5-4f46-a9a5-b0941553e3ce','9d344984-8164-45ce-a58a-715599f5fd0c','59598d21-90d5-4952-88be-e128aedda324','0f7c1a47-0a65-4d6e-a4e6-7ad5ea5e3afc','78a517bb-9686-4049-9dc2-43bba20916cb','fcf999fe-bbbf-462a-be89-2b6993501c6f','44f9ec05-5408-4778-9dc8-adbd43443af7','25766690-819a-42c1-84af-04149691a852','a923dfec-b368-49bb-af76-7a542bb5b3fb','fee7d0ca-3d74-46a1-8c22-31285af660fb','3b24f58d-1203-45d5-b718-1e2bc51bd811','48d36f2f-aa31-4018-8318-1a0e8c7d20ba','b43093b2-50ad-498f-84b1-b0181ac54d0e','b0310d94-f516-49ea-97f1-2289725a7bdb','9a58a202-91e0-47b5-bc2c-346885ab21ab','0430cc10-7141-4cc3-b4e0-07a4327e9f75','63986387-5157-4f7e-9a22-b667bc82de8f','78339b8b-1351-401d-8c03-1b5674c87f9c','9b97dadb-366a-431f-9af4-192844e9ea86','b5504148-8231-41dd-a316-96b2ec2b4b24','58ab8320-5a21-42f6-b8f2-c487cff59116','a322eb6e-6fb6-4a2a-9dee-293bf9285ae5','2f621d24-7927-4be5-a31b-8ac896cb5c21','865bfbbc-c2d7-466d-8ab3-3b1e30e87b68','f33fb2d8-9a12-4aea-bfa4-55eadbbe63c8','7f929ff1-da47-41e9-abc9-dc26f9158ae2','7a33ccb8-5728-4153-97bc-9bf85b715b20','1736fe52-9a78-442d-8d3d-d14e50791b47','9eb276eb-273d-4e20-8bf3-7fa59ab41cc5','1767d575-c13d-46be-903c-23c667341968','ad6c5b99-4840-4970-b621-0b24992ddcd7','f6b6e795-e53b-4443-8922-3011814651d9','91e17445-4349-4577-b327-90482baa177c','90c42f66-40c4-4121-901f-e27aa94818b8','7aa8f73a-b6f8-4b76-9ad7-c0e0e9ca5158')
order by "$$meta.created" asc,"key" asc limit 500
```

takes about 4 minutes, because it is using the order by index (https://explain.depesz.com/s/FXqx). if, however, i change it to limit 5000, it is done in <100ms (https://explain.depesz.com/s/OajM)

i've ran vaccuum analyze etc, but it doesn't seem to change the execution path.
i'm looking for advice, without changing the query for limit 500 vs 5000. ideally the sorted index is only used if there is no job filter.

Edit:
i have these indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX "emails_$$meta.created_key_idx"
ON vsko_mailer_api_prod.emails USING btree
("$$meta.created" ASC NULLS LAST, key ASC NULLS LAST)
TABLESPACE pg_default
WHERE NOT "$$meta.deleted";
```

also:

```
CREATE INDEX emails_emailjob
ON vsko_mailer_api_prod.emails USING btree
(job ASC NULLS LAST)
TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

and a few others that aren't relevant, i think.

I just added this one:

```
CREATE INDEX emails_emailjob_not_deleted
ON vsko_mailer_api_prod.emails USING hash
(job)
TABLESPACE pg_default
WHERE NOT "$$meta.deleted";
```

it made the limit 5000 even faster, but no difference on limit 500

edit 2:

https://explain.depesz.com/s/DOyT (limit 5000)
https://explain.depesz.com/s/Pi93 (limit 500)

all indexes:

```
"emails"    "emails_$$meta.created_key_idx" "CREATE INDEX ""emails_$$meta.created_key_idx"" ON vsko_mailer_api_prod.emails USING btree (""$$meta.created"", key) WHERE (NOT ""$$meta.deleted"")"
"emails"    "emails_created"    "CREATE INDEX emails_created ON vsko_mailer_api_prod.emails USING btree (""$$meta.created"")"
"emails"    "emails_deleted"    "CREATE INDEX emails_deleted ON vsko_mailer_api_prod.emails USING btree (""$$meta.deleted"")"
"emails"    "emails_emailjob"   "CREATE INDEX emails_emailjob ON vsko_mailer_api_prod.emails USING btree (job)"
"emails"    "emails_emailjob_not_deleted"   "CREATE INDEX emails_emailjob_not_deleted ON vsko_mailer_api_prod.emails USING hash (job) WHERE (NOT ""$$meta.deleted"")"
"emails"    "emails_lowered_job"    "CREATE INDEX emails_lowered_job ON vsko_mailer_api_prod.emails USING btree (lower((job)::text))"
"emails"    "emails_modified"   "CREATE INDEX emails_modified ON vsko_mailer_api_prod.emails USING btree (""$$meta.modified"")"
"emails"    "emails_ordered_created"    "CREATE INDEX emails_ordered_created ON vsko_mailer_api_prod.emails USING btree (""$$meta.created"") WHERE (""$$meta.deleted"" = false)"
"emails"    "emails_ordered_created_and_keys"   "CREATE INDEX emails_ordered_created_and_keys ON vsko_mailer_api_prod.emails USING btree (""$$meta.created"", key)"
"emails"    "emails_ordered_sentdate"   "CREATE INDEX emails_ordered_sentdate ON vsko_mailer_api_prod.emails USING btree (""sentDate"" DESC)"
"emails"    "emails_pkey"   "CREATE UNIQUE INDEX emails_pkey ON vsko_mailer_api_prod.emails USING btree (key)"
"emails"    "emails_status" "CREATE INDEX emails_status ON vsko_mailer_api_prod.emails USING btree (status)"
"emails"    "lowered_recipient_emailaddress_emails" "CREATE INDEX lowered_recipient_emailaddress_emails ON vsko_mailer_api_prod.emails USING btree (lower(((recipient)::json ->> 'emailAddress'::text)))"
"emails"    "lowered_recipient_person_href" "CREATE INDEX lowered_recipient_person_href ON vsko_mailer_api_prod.emails USING btree (lower(((((recipient)::json ->> 'person'::text))::json ->> 'href'::text)))"
```

Comment: Please *show us the execution plans generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers, format text)`**

Comment: Also, could you post all indexes you have on `emails` table.

Comment: Drop the index on the `ORDER BY` clause if it is in your way, and do yourself a favor and use less ridiculous names.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe i added the index for this reason: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65896487/postgres-only-using-sorted-index-for-querying-5m-records-table/65897447?noredirect=1#comment116519121_65897447

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first try should be to improve the estimate, so that PostgreSQL chooses the correct plan. This could be done with better statistics:

```
ALTER TABLE emails ALTER job SET STATISTICS 1000;
ANALYZE emails;
```

You can experiment with values up to 10000.

If that fails, you can change the `ORDER BY` clause so that it cannot be supported by the index, then PostgreSQL will always use the index on `job`:

```
...
ORDER BY "$$meta.created" + INTERVAL '0 days', key
```

Here I assume that `"$$meta.created"` is a timestamp; add something else if it is not.

Comment: my problem is i can't modify the query

Comment: I have added another idea. But sometimes you can only make things work by changing the query. That's the way it is.

Answer (score 1):

Creating test data:

```
BEGIN;
CREATE TABLE foo( id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
  key INTEGER NOT NULL, job INTEGER NOT NULL, 
  created INTEGER NOT NULL, dummy INTEGER NOT NULL,
  deleted BOOL NOT NULL );
INSERT INTO foo SELECT n, random()*10000, random()*10000, n+random()*10000, 1,
    random()>0.1 FROM generate_series(1,1000000) n;
ALTER TABLE foo ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
COMMIT;
VACUUM ANALYZE foo;

CREATE INDEX foo_job_not_deleted ON foo(job) WHERE NOT deleted;
CREATE INDEX foo_created ON foo(created,key) WHERE NOT deleted;
CREATE INDEX foo_created1 ON foo(created);
```

With these, I also get your bad plan.

One solution is to force a nested loop by using a LATERAL JOIN:

```
SELECT foo2.* FROM (VALUES (6479),(672),(6264),(5911),(6161),(7704),(2609),(4095),(271),(2363),(7299),(7330),(1990),(6523),(9261),(9490),(5013),(1131),(585),(8881),(8379),(1543),(5911),(7243),(3608),(9199),(8950),(1485),(7159),(2126),(2876),(779),(6890),(4315),(2253),(3909),(7355),(2876),(9981),(6653),(8407),(1772),(1348),(5689),(2857),(3535),(7607),(6275),(7596),(1885),(6827),(4180),(4638),(1876),(9403),(4195),(2548),(2827),(7972),(5571),(8426),(7761),(6400),(9175),(7486),(589),(3538),(8495),(2864),(5349),(4834),(1357),(6778),(6232),(7457),(6740),(5011),(946),(2918),(9981),(6903),(5565),(9396),(4482),(9796),(5925),(4971),(1304),(71),(7926),(2173),(3439),(7508),(7763),(4890),(5660),(8436),(8828),(5524),(6418)) jobs 
  JOIN LATERAL (SELECT * FROM foo WHERE foo.job=jobs.column1 AND NOT foo.deleted) foo2 ON (true)
 ORDER BY created,key LIMIT 500;
```

For each job in the VALUES clause, the LATERAL JOIN subquery will be evaluated independently. Since it hits only one job value, which is a tiny fraction of the table, this forces the optimizer to use the index to execute the subquery.

If the table contains lots of columns, most notably large TEXT columns, and the subquery returns lots of rows that will be fetched then away by the LIMIT clause, it may be beneficial to fetch only the primary key in the subquery, then after the LIMIT, join back with the main table to get all the columns that you want, only from the rows that will actually be in the final result.

Comment: great idea. i was going this way, but it's a bit slower. Laurenz's suggestion made postgres realize its mistake